# How does one set ownership of a directory using nfs4_setfacl?

Tags: linux, access-control-list, nfs4

Or put another way, when I see @OWNER in a nfs4 ACL does this @OWNER refer to a local Unix/Linux user?

I need to make an AD user (without a corresponding local account) the owner of a directory on a CentOS server.

When I say "without a corresponding local account" I mean the target directory is owned by a local service/app account that is *not* bound to any network (AD/LDAP/Kerberos) identity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can set OWNER@ using nfs4_setfacl but you can
chown a file or directory using AD/LDAP/Kerberos network identities.

I was able to chown directories using the UID:GID issued by the FreeIPA/iDM administrator.

`chown 2198753:9894732 dir/` worked for me. And `nfs4_getfacl dir/` showed OWNER@ still owned the file.